# angular-cli: Open/Close MatExpansionPanel from ts file

Tags: angular-material, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli component that contains multiple mat-expansion-panel's (https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview).

I need to open/close the expansion panels from the ts file, I am unsure how get a access to the properties on the individual expansion panels. I am getting the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

I am trying to access this element

```
<mat-expansion-panel #first="matExpansionPanel">
```

using

```
first: MatExpansionPanel;
...
this.first.open();
```

This is my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Category } from '@app/model/Enums';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';    
import { MatExpansionPanel } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-component.component.scss']
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  sub: any;
  first: MatExpansionPanel; 
  second: MatExpansionPanel; 

  constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.sub = this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {

      // Open the MatExpansionPanel with id "first"
      this.first.open();

      // Open the MatExpansionPanel with id "second"
      this.second.open();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel #first="matExpansionPanel">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Title 1
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p>Content</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<br />
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel #second="matExpansionPanel">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Title 2
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p>Content</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to instantiate your expansion panel with `@ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild('first', {static: true, read: MatExpansionPanel}) first: MatExpansionPanel;
```

Then if you want to perform the 'open' function you can only do that after the page has been set up in the `ngAfterViewInit` function.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.first.open();
}
```